# OSX- Delete <user> Library/Caches

Tags: macos, disk-space

Trying to do some housekeeping, recover disk space.
I see My Caches folder is over 10GB. Is it safe to delete?

Answer (score 0):

> I see My Caches folder is over 10GB. Is it safe to delete?

It is indeed safe to delete, but applications that depend on the data, performance will be affected. Any application designed to keep data there will continue to do so, at the expense of having to generate or download the data again, you don’t really gain much from getting rid of the data.

> It's generally safe, though a little dangerous depending, to do it but often not worth the effort.
>
> The caches in /System/Library/Caches are generally small and useful, the ones in /Library/Caches are less system caches and much more readily cleared.
>
> If you have a look in ~/Library/Caches you will find a bunch of applications have a cache in there, none of them particularly large though dropbox sometimes has a fair sized cache. This folder can run quite large just because so many apps cache something in there.

Additionally, if you do this outside of single user mode, you will want to reboot immediately afterwards.

> Of course the best way to clear the caches is to install AppleJack and do it with that in single user mode. Doing it with the System fully up can be a little dangerous. If you do it then I'd reboot immediately afterwards.

Quoted taken from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118941/is-it-safe-to-delete-library-caches) Ask Different answer.

Sources:

[Is it safe to delete ~/Library/Caches?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118941/is-it-safe-to-delete-library-caches)

I was not aware Applejack is a legacy product.  It has been suggested other software does exist though.  In the end it’s still possible to do what you want but the benefits of doing so are still negligible.

> Applejack is unfortunately well past its sell-by date now. Unsupported since maybe Lion 10.8. I'd let Onyx handle that kind of task these days. – Tetsujin 3 hours ago

Comment: Applejack is unfortunately well past its sell-by date now. Unsupported since maybe Lion 10.8. I'd let Onyx handle that kind of task these days.